# ruby-gmail: Uncaught exception: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtMk

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, gmail

I can manually login my account, but when i use ruby-gmail, it will raise err

this is my code

```
require 'gmail'

gmail = Gmail.new("myname@gmail.com", "passwd")

gmail.deliver do
  to "rorocodeath@gmail.com"
  subject "Having fun in Puerto Rico!"
  text_part do
    body "Text of plaintext message."
  end
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body "<p>Text of <em>html</em> message.</p>"
  end
  add_file __FILE__
end
```

this is my full output

```
Uncaught exception: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtMk

    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:969:in `check_auth_response'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_plain'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:732:in `authenticate'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-gmail-0.3.1/lib/smtp_tls.rb:57:in `do_tls_start'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-gmail-0.3.1/lib/smtp_tls.rb:18:in `start'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/message.rb:248:in `deliver!'
    /home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-gmail-0.3.1/lib/gmail.rb:107:in `deliver'
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_plans/ex/ex.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

**update**

solution: https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/apppasswords > generate new for mail > remember it > fill it in ruby-gmail passwd

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Gmail has some security features that have to be enabled/disabled
1 - Inside your gmail account go to Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP and enable the protocols(s) that you wish to use

2 - Enable access of less secure apps https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: As of Feb. 2015 I only had to do #2 to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can check https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha as well. You can unblock application url by unlocking it.

Comment: There is no option to unlock captha. It is asking for signin from the other device we are trying to login

Comment: First login in gmail account. Then open open https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue.

Comment: After logged in to my device, I opened the link. But it is asking to login from another device we are using. I.e., may be in heroku virtual machine in production

Answer (score 2):

I change gem 'ruby-gmail' to gem 'gmail', it work.

**update**: it can't fix my question, gem 'gmail' only ignore my error(raise error bug)